# Can you have multiple gitignore configurations for same directory?

Tags: git

Say I have a staging area that has some additional files necessary for the staging area, that I don't want in my repository. Nor do I want to actually include those ignore patterns in the shared `.gitignore` file.

Ideal what I'd like to do is have a kind of "local only" `.gitignore` for just that environment, in addition to the shared `.gitignore`. Is that possible to do?

Comment: If your staging area is in a separate directory, you can just put a `.gitignore` in that directory - it doesn't have to be at project root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
$GIT_DIR/info/exclude
.git/info/exclude
```

It is local to the repo, and won't be pushed.
It works for untracked files.

The other approach to ignore files (already versioned) temporarily would be

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- [<file>...]
```

Comment: Since .gitignore has a higher precedence, I'm afraid this cannot work.

Comment: @ElpieKay Why? If those *additional* files are *not* in the local `.gitignore`, they will be ignored by the `exclude` file.

Comment: Don't forget `git config core.excludesFile` (usually set with `--global`, but can technically be set per-repo), which defaults to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore`